# get value of string outside void async method?

Tags: java, android, mysql, asynchronous

How do I get the value of String r outside the getInformation method? Specifically, I want to set String stringpwd equal to String r. (getInformation is a void method)

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I only want to set the value stringpwd after success has been completed.

```
                String user = emailaddress.getText().toString().trim();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString().trim();
                db.getInformation("password", user, new DatabaseHelper.MyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(String r) {
                        // Use result

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(Throwable t) {
                        // Display error

                    }

                });

            

               String stringpwd = r;
```

Comment: What language is this code in? Please tag with those first.

Comment: It's in java. I'll tag.

Comment: That'll help get the right attention. As a note tags like `void` are really meaningless and should be avoided. People won't be looking for those sorts of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable (example used below: userCpy), and initialise or store the value of string r in that variable making it availabe, elsewhere.

```
                String userCpy = null;         
                int flag = 0;    
                String user = emailaddress.getText().toString().trim();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString().trim();
                db.getInformation("password", user, new DatabaseHelper.MyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(String r) {
                        // Use result
                       userCpy = r;
                       flag = 1;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(Throwable t) {
                        // Display error

                    }

                });

               if(flag==1)
                   String stringpwd = userCpy;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I only want to set the value stringpwd after success has been completed.

Comment: @AnonymousCardinal Well, just change the `String userCpy = "";` to `String userCpy = null` and `stringpwd` will be null on failure.

Comment: getInformation is async, so I don't want to set stringpwd until success returns what userCpy is.

Comment: I added an int variable flag, to make sure that the stringpwd = userCpy (i.e. stringpwd = r) occurs only when success block is executed.

Comment: And as @pirho mentioned, it would be better in your case to assign an initial value of null to userCpy instead of "".